# exceptions handling after button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to stop processing after an exception is found and displayed it to the user but i cant get my code to stop once one has been found...

```
try
{
   //Someting
}
catch (Exception ex)       
{ 
     lblerror.Text = (ex.Message);

     //// STOP CODE WHEN EXCEPTION IS FOUND SO USER CAN FIX THE CAUSE            
}
finally
{
    Response.Redirect("//hud/account.aspx");
}
```

i have tried throw and return commands with no luck. Im new to all of this and i have googled it with no luck... any ideas what im missing ? or maybe i have the wrong idea all together. its a button click event that is tied in with a textbox,  when an exception is thrown it will display the error in a label for the user to resolve (too many numbers...etc ). When corrected and the button is clicked again, this time without throwing an exception the users should be redirected. Any help would be great.

Comment: You may throw the exception further into the main-method (or any other) by catching it there. This way you "bubble" through the stacks of your application until everything is fine again.

Comment: If you want to stop processing the code, then don't handle any errors and it will automatically stop execution

Comment: finally block will be always executed

Comment: @Craig W. the exception is comping from a third party. And it contains detail of what needs to be fixed in order to resolve the problem. i had hope that i could right it so that when the button is click and in information is submitted and there was no exceptions coming from the 3rd party that the page would redirect to the final page.

Comment: A far I can understand once the exception is encountered it is behaving appropriately and throwing the error message as required. But after the error has been fixed and your click the button again, it does not re-direct. Right ? If so, you should try by just adding redirect logic in the page and remove the try and catch blocks ? Let me know if this works ?

Comment: check my answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789362/exceptions-handling-after-button-click-event/22789752#22789752

Comment: @Arafat it does re-direct, but it does so whether or not the page throws and exception. I want it to stop if an exception is found and display it to the user rather than just going on to the next page.

Comment: Then you should remove the redirect logic from the finally block. Because finally block always gets executed weather an exception has encountered or not. Probably you should try something as listed below by @user3401335. He has moved the redirect as the last statement in the try block. Your core logic stays on the top and if it is successful and no exception has encountered then it allows you to redirect. Otherwise it stops you right there with the help of exception code... let me put this in answer and you can try it.

Comment: @user3266908 see the below my answer it will help you. when you get the expection set a variable iserror = true. that mean there is any error validate it in the finally block..if it's true don;t redirect if false mean no error redirect it

Comment: @Arafat your right his code did work but i for some reason believed that it was not going to be that easy..lol thanks for the help.  user3401335 and Arafat

Comment: The fact that the exception is coming from a third party would have been useful information to include in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not use finally.

```
try
{
   //Someting
   Response.Redirect("//hud/account.aspx");
}
catch (Exception ex)       
{ 
     lblerror.Text = (ex.Message);

     //// STOP CODE WHEN EXCEPTION IS FOUND SO USER CAN FIX THE CAUSE            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using exceptions to do validation or flow-of-control. You should simply check the conditions in the code and present a message if the values don't satisfy the conditions.

e.g.

```
int foo;

if( !Int32.TryParse( something.Text, out foo ) )
{
    lblError.Text = "You must enter a number.";
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect...
}
```

Comment: And this was down-voted why? It's generally considered good practice to not use exceptions for flow-of-control.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the redirect logic from the finally block. Because finally block always gets executed weather an exception has encountered or not.

Probably you should try something as listed below by @user3401335. He has moved the redirect as the last statement in the try block. Your core logic stays on the top and if it is successful and no exception has encountered then it allows you to redirect. Otherwise it stops you right there with the help of exception code...

You should try as follows:

```
try
{
    //Something
    Response.Redirect("//hud/account.aspx");
}
catch (Exception ex)       
{ 
    lblerror.Text = (ex.Message);
    // STOP CODE WHEN EXCEPTION IS FOUND SO USER CAN FIX THE CAUSE            
}
finally
{
    // PUT IN SOMETHING HERE THAT YOU WANT ALWAYS TO GET EXECUTED
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
bool iserror = false;
try
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = b / a;
    Response.Redirect("//hud/account.aspx");
}

catch (Exception ex)      
{
  lblerror.Text = (ex.Message);
    iserror = true;
}
finally
{
    if (!iserror)
    {
      //do something if you want
    }
}
```

Comment: This is overly complex. Why not just put the `Response.Redirect` in the last line of the `try` section?

Comment: @RichardEverett: user3266908 want's the finally block... i am agree with you